# How to save values of multiple data types in a .txt file in binary mode in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5, binaryfiles

I am trying to save a set of parameters in a text file in binary mode. By the word **set** i mean there will be 2 values like a pair.
For e.g - Parameter=weight , Value=35.
The code i have is:

```
with open(os.path.join(path, "parameters.txt"), "wb") as out:
    for parameter, value in parameters:
        out.write("{}: {}\n".format(bytearray(parameter,'utf-8'),(bytearray(value,'utf-8'))
```

But the main issue is that the values in `value` is not of the same type. It has `int , float , string , tuple` types of values in it. So with the above code i get error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Is there a general way to save the values in `value` in binary mode ? i.e one single functionality for all the values inside `value`

> Note: I am using python 3.5 and ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: you mention both 'binary' and 'text'... if text is important: if you need tuples, look at pyyaml, if not, look at the internal json module. if binary is more important, take a look at msgpack.

Comment: By 'text' i mean the file type will be a .txt file but all operation of writing will be in binary mode of python.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use something like this:

```
import os
parameters = {"some": "some1", "some2": "some3", "1": 123, 123: 123}
s = ""
path = "."
########
to_s = lambda x: (str(x) if not isinstance(x, str) else x)   
with open(os.path.join(path, "parameters.txt"), "wb") as out:
    for parameter, value in parameters.items():
        s += "{}: {}\n".format(to_s(parameter), to_s(value))
    out.write(bytearray(s, 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: The variable ```parameters``` has been passed as an argument to a function and within this function i am writing the above mentioned code (code in my post) . So i cannot manually overwrite it . But yes the format which you have mentioned  
```parameters = {"some" : "some1" , "some2" : 34 , "some3" : (2,9)}``` is somewhat correct except the fact that few values are of different datatypes.

Comment: In such case you can add simple function to convert all values to string. (I add to_s in example).

Comment: Code above  ######## helper part for check that scripts worked, your need only that under ########.